# Customizing VSCode theme: how to keep original icon color for the focused item in autocomplete list?

Tags: visual-studio-code, colors, themes

The February 2021 version brought a breaking change for the colors of autocomplete lists:

- https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_54#_updated-listtree-ui

Where we have the following settings for the colors of the focused item:

- `quickInputList.focusIconForeground`
- `quickInputList.focusForeground`
- `quickInputList.focusBackground`

The three work fine.

However, when setting `focusIconForeground`, it seems that we can override the color of the icon... but what if I want to **keep the original color** of the icon, even when the item is focused?

For example, suppose I have the following settings:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "[Default Light+]": {
        "quickInputList.focusIconForeground": "#ff0000",
        "quickInputList.focusForeground": "#000000",
        "quickInputList.focusBackground": "#e0e0e0",
    },
},
```

If so, this is the rendered autocomplete list:

[image]

See how the icon of the focused item is **red**. I want it to remain purple, its original color.

So, what setting can I use in `quickInputList.focusIconForeground` to keep the icon at its original color?

As a side note... I'm using "Default Light+" theme, but I noticed that many other themes (like "Quiet Light" and "Monokai") do exactly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to dig into the actual source code of VSCode in order to find this. What happen is: the suggestion box icon is called [product icon](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/product-icon-theme), which is actually a [glyph icon font](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/icons-in-labels) that can be themed. It ships with *no color*, because the color is defined by the active color theme.

When the suggestion box is rendered, VSCode checks if current theme has defined a color to the icon. If there is no color, a default color is given *according to the icon type*. However, if the color theme defined a color to the icon, this color is used, *regardless of the icon type* – that is, the theme overrides the color. The parameter for this color is `editorSuggestWidget.selectedIconForeground`, as noted in [JayDev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14291011/jaydev)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68322086/6923555). The code which does this can be seen [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/editor/contrib/suggest/suggestWidget.ts#L1008).

Now the theme I'm using, "Default Light+", does override this color, and there is *no way* to clear this overriding in VSCode settings file. Other themes do not override, and those themes show the original icon color, which is the behavior I want. So, what I had to do was simply modify the theme, inside VSCode installation folder, commenting out the offending line, which can be found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/extensions/theme-defaults/themes/light_vs.json#L28). For reference, in VSCode installation folder, it's line 28 of this file:

```
resources\app\extensions\theme-defaults\themes\light_vs.json
```

The line itself to be commented out is:

```
"list.activeSelectionIconForeground": "#FFF"
```

Another solution would simply be to create another theme, based off "Default Light+", with this fix. However, if the theme is updated in the future, I'd have to keep the pace, something I don't want to do. So, what I'm doing is adding this fix to [this patch](https://github.com/rodrigocfd/vscode-font-patch) I wrote a while ago to automate other VSCode customizations.

**Note:** All source code references were taken off VSCode commit [da77887 (June 10, 2021)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/da77887f997f15da82eac4fa1a201e96aabfda82). These references may, obviously, change in the future.

Comment: I gotta give to you, the patch idea's pretty F'n cool. I like that it is written in rust.